# External Content Type : How to display label on lookup columns (without unable edit / new form)?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, lookup-column, external-content-type, external-list

I have a SQL Server Table **A** with a foreign key with reference to **B** :

- id_A [int auto_increment PK]
- name [varchar()]
- ref_B [int FK_ref_to_B]

I try to display **A** in an External List based on External Content which :

- During reading the list : display the label of lookup columns (instead of displaying the id)
- During edit / create element : have a button for "browsing" **B** values (functionality of a lookup column)

**Method :**

I followed some tutorials like :

- [sandeepnakarmi.com](http://www.sandeepnakarmi.com/2014/09/create-external-lists-with-foreign-key-association-and-use-user-friendly-column-names/)
- [lightningtools.com](https://lightningtools.com/bcs/lookup-foreign-key-values-in-external-lists/)

According to the first link, I also created a view named **view_A** that make the link between **A** and **B** and select the label of **B** instead of the id. I used Sharepoint Designer 2013 and followed these steps : (1) I created all operations based on the table **A**, (2) I created associations to the table **B**, (3) I removed "Read Items" and "Read List", recreated them with the view **view_A** and paid attention to give the same columns 'display name' of other operations created during step 1.

**Behaviour (Trouble) :**

The trouble become during step (3). When I create operations and associations, everything is ok, but when I use the view for creating "Read Items" and "Read List" operations :

- Label are displayed instead of the id (OK)
- When I try to edit / create an item, I got this error message :

> Unable to find the default edit / new form for list ...

The only solution for the moment is to remove "Edit" and "New" operations, but they are expected.

**Question :**

Can I display label and using SQL view while using column lookup ? If yes : what I could miss ?